# How do we match between two pandas dataframes by mapping two columns (.map)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do we match between two pandas dataframes by mapping two columns (.map)? I tried to map using one column, but this created duplicates. To solve this, two columns should be used for mapping to create a unique row.

Below is an example with the expected output:

**df1**

```
idx a1 b1   c1 d1 e1
12  4  x10  2  2  5
13  5  x2   3  5  4
14  6  x4   6  9  6
15  7  x13  7  9  2
```

**df2**

```
idx a2  b2 c2 d2 e2
1   x2  x1 2  2  4
2   x8  x2 6  9  8
3   x6  x4 7  9  5
4   x4  x7 6  8  9
```

By mapping `c1` with `c2` and `d1` with `d2` the value of `e2` should be updated with the value  of `e1` so **df2** should look like this

**df2**

```
idx a2  b2 c2 d2 e2
1   x2  x1 2  2  5 (updated)
2   x8  x2 6  9  6 (updated)
3   x6  x4 7  9  2 (updated) 
4   x4  x7 6  8  9
```

Comment: why isn't the 3rd row updated from 5 -> 2?

Comment: @cs95 Thanks for highlighting this; I forgot to update it in the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)/[`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) :

```
lcols, rcols = ["c2", "d2"], ["c1", "d1"] #mappings
​
df2["e2"] = (df2.merge(df1, left_on=lcols, right_on=rcols, how="left")
                 ["e1"].combine_first(df2["e2"])
            )
```

Output :

```
print(df2)

   idx  a2  b2  c2  d2   e2
0    1  x2  x1   2   2  5.0 # <- updated
1    2  x8  x2   6   9  6.0 # <- updated
2    3  x6  x4   7   9  2.0 # <- updated
3    4  x4  x7   6   8  9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join by both DataFrames with replace not matched values by original column in [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df2['e2'] = (df2.reset_index()
                .merge(df1, left_on=['c2','d2'], right_on=['c1','d1'], how='left')
                .set_index('index')['e1'].fillna(df2['e2']))
```

If default index in `df2.index`:

```
df2['e2'] = (df2.merge(df1, left_on=['c2','d2'], right_on=['c1','d1'], how='left')['e1']
                .fillna(df2['e2']))
```

Or use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) by `MulitIndex`:

```
d = df1.set_index(['c1','d1'])['e1'].to_dict()

df2['e2'] = (pd.Series(df2.set_index(['c2','d2']).index.map(d).to_numpy(), index=df2.index)
               .fillna(df2['e2']))
print (df2)
   idx  a2  b2  c2  d2   e2
0    1  x2  x1   2   2  5.0
1    2  x8  x2   6   9  6.0
2    3  x6  x4   7   9  2.0
3    4  x4  x7   6   8  9.0
```